# Determine the changes made to Internet Explorer security zones

Tags: windows, security, internet-explorer

Here you can see that the Local Intranet settings have been changed because the button labeled "Default level" is currently enabled:

[image]

How can you determine which settings were changed from the default level?

Comment: As the administrator you look at the policy deploying these settings.